# NullPointerException when I use bitmap.compress(2021)

Tags: java, android, api

I wanna convert File to bitmap and then bitmap to byte[]. When I debug, file is created and bitmap, too. also it can be converted to byte. But in while(), there is nullpointerException error on bitmap.compress, and it is same when I emulate it. I don't know why at first or second iteration, it is okay, but after that it isn't.

This is error code.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.fastplusindia.customer, PID: 5263
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
at com.fastplusindia.customer.activity.RegisterActivity.getStringImage(RegisterActivity.java:421)
at com.fastplusindia.customer.activity.RegisterActivity.upload(RegisterActivity.java:645)
at com.fastplusindia.customer.activity.RegisterActivity.access$100(RegisterActivity.java:81)
at com.fastplusindia.customer.activity.RegisterActivity$5.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:223)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is my code-

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {`enter code here`

if (requestCode == 2) {
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
InputStream imageStream = null;
try {
imageStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(selectedImage));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
final Bitmap imagebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
Bitmap scaleBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imagebitmap, (int) (imagebitmap.getWidth() * 0.1), (int) (imagebitmap.getHeight()*0.1) ,  true);

String path = getPath(selectedImage);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
ExifInterface exif;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
try {
exif = new ExifInterface(path);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
switch (orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
matrix.postRotate(90);
break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
matrix.postRotate(180);
break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
matrix.postRotate(270);
break;
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}


Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaleBitmap, 0, 0, scaleBitmap.getWidth(), scaleBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
photo.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
imageByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

}

}

}
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
imageByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
return Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to take image then make it byte array and then send to server type of thing??

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap you passed to the getStringImage method is null, that's why you're getting a null pointer exception

Comment: The compress function is called twice. Why do my you think its this one?

Comment: Because it's where the application crashed

Comment: It was there where a NullPointerException was thrown. You did not catch that exception so you let your app crash only then.